# How to declare protected members in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, protected

I am learning object oriented programming in python3. I knew that when I declare a member variable with double leading underscores, it becomes private (I mean to say not accessible outside the class definition). Now I want to get such private member in the subclass via inheritance (I mean to say that, I want to declare protected member). Please help me guys. Thanks in advance. Here is the code I tried.

```
class Parent():
    __x = 50


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__x)

x = Child()
print(Parent.__x)
```

My expected answer is 50, but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Child' object has no attribute '_Child__x'
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "private" and "protected" in Python. If you're reading a tutorial that uses those terms, it was written by someone who only understands C++ or Java, and you should find a better tutorial.

Comment: The actual distinction Python has is: `x` is part of your stable/public/user interface. `_x` is, by convention, unstable/private/internal, in the sense that you make no promises about what happens if people use it. `__x` means you want to make sure superclasses and subclasses can use the same name without any accidental overriding. That's it.

Comment: "I knew that when I declare a member variable with double leading underscores, it becomes private (I mean to say not accessible outside the class definition)." No, it does not. Python attributes are never private. Also, you have created a class variable here, not a member (instance) variable.